# How to translate a model header title?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am use a `QAbstractTableModel` model that the horizontal header title need to translate different language.
But when I use `pylupdate` and `linguist` tool, it seems not working.
So how can I translate the `QAbstractTableModel`  header when app start when select a different language?

**Code Snippet**

```py
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 4))  # type: np.ndarray
        self._columns = ["第一列", "第二列", "第三列", "第四列"]

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return QApplication.translate("Model", self._columns[section])

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> int:
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> int:
        return self._data.shape[1]

view = QTableView()
view.setModel(Model())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP`:

```py
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 4))  # type: np.ndarray
        self._columns = [
            QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("Model", "First"),
            QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("Model", "Second"),
            QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("Model", "Third"),
            QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("Model", "Fourth"),
        ]

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> int:
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> int:
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.tr(self._columns[section])

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data[index.row()][index.column()])
```

<sub>The complete example is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/68554025).</sub>